# Footer won't go to bottom

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm doing a website and I have a big problem : the footer doesn't go to bottom.
The thing is that I have to do tabs and so I'd like my footer to go to the bottom of the content of the tab currently selected.

I've made a lot of research and yet, none resolved my problem.

My [HTML code](http://pastebin.com/gUZbPrVe) 
My [CSS code](http://pastebin.com/7APN9wEa)

In the html I tried :

- `< div style="clear:both"></div>`
- `< br clear="all" />`

In the css (for the markup footer):

- `clear : both`
- `position absolute with bottom 0` (which doesn't work very
  well since it's absolute so it doesn't move with the content of the tabs)
- things with footerwrapper

Whether I put the `< footer>< footer/>` in the body or not doesn't change anything ...

I really don't understand why it doesn't work.
What should I do ? I've been struggling with this problem for hours and still, I didn't find any solution.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: sorry I'm not able to see your code in that page for slow connection. So, try to 'float' first before 'clear'

Comment: Do not use position: absolute for main content, footer IS in bottom, but have to understand that your main content with absolute position do not exists for footer.

Comment: Well, I'll have to find a way to get rid of the absolute AND keep the current looking of the webpage ... Looks like I'll have a good time.